# python getting partial name and use as variable

Tags: python

I'd like to have a function that receives a list of strings and converts them to variable to be used with some extra constant prefix

For example:  `element_list=['em1', 'em2', 'em3']`

```
def myFunction(list):
    for element in list:
        XXX
        get_data(pref.element)
```

Where the pref.element shall be already a variable name. What I'm missing is the XXX.

Comment: The real question here is: why do you care about variable names? The `get_data` function does not have access to that name, so what's the point?

Comment: Are you just looking for a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)?

Comment: Where do the references of the existing variables live now?